# reponsive web design without javascript for IE <=8. Is it possible?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, media-queries, javascript

I have been trying to build my own web site; I was reading about RWD(responsive web design). I was having issues with IE. I could have default style display for IE<=8, but I saw   [1]: http://www.etondigital.com site You can visit the site and in IE 7 with javascript disabled still function responsively. I am kind of having hard time figuring how that is possible. It changes from three column to one column. If you understand the site functionality, how that is possible let me know. Thanks

/***********I have added my code, and in relation to the link I attached how could i achieve in Ie8 and below without javascript to change it from three row to one row without any notice like eton digital website

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Second Theme</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
            <!--so html 5 tags work in ie browsers 8 and lower-->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <style type="text/css">
        body{
   font:normal 100% Cambria, Georgia, serif;
   margin:10px;
}

.wrapper{
    margin: 0em auto;
    width: 93.75%;      /* 960/1024 */
    background:gray;
    padding:.625em;

}


.box{
width:29.847%;/*274/918*/
    float:left;
    margin-right:2em;
}

.clear{
    clear:both;
}

        </style>
    <body>
       <div class="warapper">
        <aside class="bottom_sidebar">
            <div class="box one">
                <h1>One</h1>
                <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
                    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard 
                    dummy text  ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
                     took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a</p>

            </div>
            <div  class="box">
                <h1>Two</h1>
                <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
                    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard 
                    dummy text  ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
                     took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a</p>
            </div>
            <div  class="box">
                <h1>Three</h1>
                <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
                    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard 
                    dummy text  ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
                     took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a</p>
            </div> 
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </aside>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please check whether you really have JavaScript disabled. When I visit the etondigital.com site with IE 9 in IE 7 mode with scripting disabled, it is shown in simple one-column layout without responsiveness.

Comment: @JukkaK I see three columns initially in eton digital when I decrease the size, it changes from three to one row. I have disabled javascript and am in ie7 mode

Answer (score 1):

If you used percentage based widths for all of the block level elements, you could make your site responsive without having to use the `@media` CSS at-rule. Otherwise, you will need to use JavaScript in order for a site to respond to media queries in IE.

Comment: I have added what am doing, and I have difficulty to achieve in similar ways as the link I provided, eton digital site, please look my code

Answer (score 0):

The best way, and also the simplest way, is through bootstrap.  It is compatible from IE7+ and does as much or as little as you want.  It is not a template, but a set of .css files which pre coded classes to allow you to build the best possible responsive layout in a small amount of time. I would suggest spending some time googling Bootstrap and reading all about the details, but **Bootstrap is definitely the way to go.**

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html

Comment: How would Bootstrap solve the responsivity issue? The bootstrap-responsive.css uses `@media` queries, which are not supported by IE <= 8. No amount of pre-coded classes can change this.

Comment: @raphael I have added what am doing, and I have difficulty to achieve in similar ways as the link I provided, eton digital site, please look my code

Comment: You would think so but there are ways around the fact that ie8 doesn't support media queries. Read on my friend. If you look at bootstrap's website you will see they support IE 7 +

Comment: Btw, the eton website was built with bootstrap